# ViewPager problems

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-wrap-content

I set ViewPager's height wrap_content but it doesn't work. I tried answers in other similar questions but they didn't solve my problem. my activity_main code is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#C49A1544"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"/>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard_margin_x2"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I have 3 fragment layouts. really sorry for my low English, I am a beginner in Android app development please help me.

Comment: `but it doesn't work` what doesn't work ?

Comment: wrap_content doesn't work in view pager

Comment: i don't understand what you mean when you say that it doesn't work, what's happening ?

Comment: if you look at the image you will see white space in below of pages, i want to wrap content

Comment: ahh i see, why not use match_parent for it then ?

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Comment: We need to see the entire layout

Comment: Ok i put the entire layout.

Comment: No one to answer??

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself. If we use UltraViewPager library instead of the default, the problem will be solved, but this library has bugs. Anyway, thank you for trying to help me with your comments.